# why using た in これからはどうしたものか？

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrases

The phrase 「これから」 refers to the future, while 「た」 refers to the past. Why can they be used in this way?

Comment: Have you checked the meaning the of どうしたものか? It's a set phrase.